# Exchange Local Continuous Replication - Seeding Fails

Tags: exchange-2007, replication

When setting up Local Continous Replication on an Exchange 2007 server's larger database, the wizard consistently fails with a message along the lines of:

> The log file xxxx for SERVERNAME\Your Storage Group is missing in the
>   production copy.  Continuous replication for this storage group is
>   blocked. If you removed the log file, please replace it. If the log is
>   lost, the passive copy will need to be reseeded using the
>   Update-StorageGroupCopy cmdlet in the Exchange Management Shell.

The smaller database succeeds.

Why is this happening, and how do I set up the larger database for Local Continuous Replication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Exchange database has circular logging enabled, Exchange deletes your transaction logs after writing the data in them to the database.  It's possible that the copy wizard won't be able copy your database to the second location before the logs are deleted.

What worked for me was to:

1. Suspend replication on the database where seeding failed.
2. Dismount the database.
3. Delete all files out of the copy (LCR) folder (logs and database).
4. Copy the database manually from the production location to the copy (LCR) location.
5. Mount the database.
6. Resume Replication.

An alternate solution might be to disable circular logging, restart the Microsoft Exchange Information Store Service or unmount/remount the database, re-run the wizard, re-enable circular logging, and restart the service/unmount and remount the database again.